# Model sequelize nodejs TypeError: (intermediate value).init is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm making an application with ORM sequelize for the first time, I got to the model part, but when I run it it points me to an error that I can't solve, if anyone knows or can help me, thank you in advance, I'll leave the model code below and the error message

```
const Model = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = require('sequelize');

class User extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {
      sequelize
    })
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

this is the error message:
super.init({
^

TypeError: (intermediate value).init is not a function
at Function.init (/home/lagos/Documents/MyProjectSGBD/api/src/models/User.js:7:11)
at Object. (/home/lagos/Documents/MyProjectSGBD/api/src/database/index.js:8:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object. (/home/lagos/Documents/MyProjectSGBD/api/src/app.js:4:1)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your imports are not correct. It should be

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
```

Also, why not define models with `sequelize.define`.
If you are defining them through extending Model, then try this

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:');

class User extends Model {}

User.init({
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  password: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  email: DataTypes.STRING,
},{
  sequelize
});

console.log(User === sequelize.models.User); // true
```

Reference -> https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html

Comment: I agree this answer